# String letter percentages in Haskell

Tags: string, haskell, tuples

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that will take a String say "PLATYPUS" and will return the relative percentages of Characters in that word i.e. characterPercentages "PLATYPUS" would return: [(P,25),(A,13),(L,13),(S,13),(T,13),(U,13),(Y,13)]. I know I can use tuples, but after that I'm a bit stumped?

Comment: Try to work out the question a bit more. How would get those tuples out of the string? What functions you expect to encounter? What's coming in? What's coming out?

Comment: Take a look at `Data.Map`, I think it'll help you out a lot

Comment: Perhaps you should try absolute frequencies first, like in `[(P,2),(A,1),(L,1),(S,1),(T,1),(U,1),(Y,1)]`. Suppose you can compute that for some string. Then figure out how to add just one letter to the answer you have. When you have everything in place, convert your values to percentages.

Comment: How do I look at Data.Map?

Comment: From ghci, you could try `:m Data.Map` and `:browse Data.Map`, and you could google for "Data.Map haskell" for the documentation

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to understand what are you going to get.

As I understand, you wish to have

```
type String = [Char] --already in Prelude

String -> [(Char,Int)]
"PLATYPUS" -=> [('P',2),('A',1),('L',1),('S',1),('T',1),('U',1),('Y',1)]
```

You could combine `group` grouping lists from [Data-List](http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/haskell2010-1.1.1.0/Data-List.html) with mapping using `length` function

```
String   -> [[Char]]
[[Char]] -> [(Char,Int)]
```

**UPDATED**

If we talk about first part - count letters, we can do next:

```
> :m Data.List
> map (\c -> (head c, length c)) $ group $ sort "PLATYPUSAAA"
[('A',4),('L',1),('P',2),('S',1),('T',1),('U',1),('Y',1)]
```

So, let's found relative numbers, we change `length c` to `100*(length c) 'div' ls`:

```
> let frqLetters s = let ls = length s in 
     map (\c -> (head c, 100 * (length c) `div` ls)) $ group $ sort s
> frqLetters "PLATYPUSAAA"
[('A',36),('L',9),('P',18),('S',9),('T',9),('U',9),('Y',9)]
```

Comment: I understand that the group function splits the list into a list of lists but will the length function give the length of the list of lists as a whole? Or can it give the length of each individual sub-list?

Comment: @Eddie, yes, sublists, using `map`, `map (\c -> (head c, length c))`

Comment: Is there a way of doing this function using zip and/or unzip?

Comment: @Eddie I update my answer. Now you need to use another `map`, but divide second part of tuple to `length` of String

Comment: Is there a way of ordering this so instead of it being alphabetical it lists the letters with the highest frequency first in descending order? i.e. so the P is before the L?

Comment: though it is a beginners question I really like `import Control.Arrow ((&&&))` -> `(head &&& length)` instead of the anonymous function `(\c -> (head c, length c))`