# Size order letter percentages function

Tags: string, haskell, tuples

This is in reference to an earlier question.

[String letter percentages in Haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19323958/string-letter-percentages-in-haskell)

Because at the moment what is returned is in alphabetical order, whereas I want it in size order, starting with the letter with the highest percentage and going down?

Comment: Have you tried [sortby](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Data-List.html#v:sortBy).  Write a function that takes a tuple and returns an Ordering and you're done.

Comment: What does sortBy do? How it it different to sort?

Comment: Click the link, read the type

Comment: `import Data.Ord (comparing)`, `import Data.List (sortBy,group)` are both your friends

Answer (score 1):

You want a function like

```
letterFrqs :: String -> [(Char, Float)]
```

with

```
letterFrqs "PLATYPUS" == [('A',36),('P',18),('L',9),('S',9),('T',9),('U',9),('Y',9)]
```

given one

```
frqLetters :: String -> [(Char, Float)]
```

with

```
frqLetters "PLATYPUS" == [('A',36),('L',9),('P',18),('S',9),('T',9),('U',9),('Y',9)]
```

So what you need is

```
letterFrqs = sortEm . frqLetters
```

with

```
sortEm :: [(Char, Float)] -> [(Char, Float)]
```

---

How can we write `sortEm`? Well, we can `sort` the `Float`s as they are, `sort :: [Float] -> [Float]`. We'd like to lift that sorting into our tuples.

Generally, Haskell functions may sometimes have similarly named cousins. In this case, `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]` has a cousin named `sortBy :: (a -> a -> Ordering) -> [a] -> [a]`. The difference here is that the `Ord` instance is "inlined". To be more specific, here's `Ord`

```
instance Eq a => Ord a where
  compare :: a -> a -> Ordering
```

So we notice that `sortBy` just replaces `sort`'s `Ord` constraint with the exact function that defines an `Ord` instance, `compare`. Indeed, that's exactly how `sort` is implemented

```
sort = sortBy compare
```

We can write `sortEm` by writing code equivalent to an `Ord` instance on tuples which just compares the second element (our `Float`s!).

---

So how do we do that? Well, we can use the `Ord` instance for `Float`.

```
compareOurTuples (char1, percent1) (char2, percent2) = compare percent1 percent2

sortEm = sortBy compareOurTuples
```

Now, someone with a clever eye for Haskell might notice that we could also write `compareOurTuples` like this

```
compareOurTuples tup1 tup2 = compare (snd tup1) (snd tup2)
```

This is a common idiom, kind of like pre-composing a function "twice". It's called `on` and it's in `Data.Function`.

```
compareOurTuples = compare `on` snd
```

But, this is *also* a pretty common idiom, combining `compare` and `on`, so even that has a special name. In `Data.Ord` we have

```
comparing f = compare `on` f
```

And so we can actually be very economical while writing `sortEm`.

```
sortEm = comparing snd
```

And this is probably the way someone would actually write this code.

```
letterFrqs = sortBy (comparing snd) . frqLetters
```

It sort of reads like English now.